# How does callback of setImmediate executed before setTimeout() when scheduled in Poll phase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lifecycle, setimmediate

These are quote from Nodejs documentation and blogs.

> If an immediate timer is queued from inside an executing callback, that timer will not be triggered until the next event loop iteration.

> setImmediate() will always be executed before any timers if scheduled within an I/O cycle, independently of how many timers are present.

According to Node docs, setImmediate()'s callback should be **executed in next tick**. However, when it's scheduled in the I/O(aka poll phase), setImmediate's callback is always triggered before timer.

```
fs.readFile('xx', () => {
  setTimeout(() => { console.log('2 timeout'); }, 0);
  setImmediate(() => { console.log('1 Immediate'); });
});
> 1 Immediate
> 2 timeout
```

My question is how does it work exactly? Does setImmediate()'s callback executed **in current tick** instead of next tick thus it logs before timer?

Note: I have read all the suggested existing posts but I don't see any post talking about this particular use case where setImmediate is scheduled under I/O phase.

Comment: There just queues under the hood, and setImmediate queue get processed before other async queues microtask / macrotasks during the event loop.

Comment: @Keith, not really.

Comment: Not really?, not sure what that comment is meant to mean..